# Looking for an epub reader for mathematics texts

Tags: epub, reader

I read math textbooks. This requires constant shifting back and forward to specific places in the book via internal hyperlinks, bookmarks and (sub)chapter headings. The focus that I really need is navigability, and I'm surprised how little of it is implemented in epub readers. I usually read pdf, but I would like to read them as epub (or similarly reflowable format) and I have some books already as epub.

These features are really essential

1. Access to table of contents
2. Back and forward navigation buttons (like in a browser, so you can follow links within the book and return to your position
3. Bookmarking
4. Text search
5. Annotation
6. Tablet suitable interface (reading on Microsoft Surface Pro 8, Windows 11)
7. Correctly renders mathematics within (not on top of) text.
8. Load epub (or other reflowable format) from filesystem

I know there are a lot of readers available and to so far I've tested Calibre (fails #7, barely #6), Icecream (fails #2) and Freda (fails #2, barely #4,#7) don't do all of the above. Kindle, Kobo and Vitalsource don't seem to do #8. Is there an epub reader that will do all of this?

Comment: been 6mths, find anything?

Comment: Nothing yet, though I gave up shortly after this post